# Jenkins - How to list build choices from successful builds of another project

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Assume I have two projects `build` and `deploy`.

I expect the build parameters of `deploy` to be a dropdown so that I can select which one to deploy.

All the dropdown items are build names of successful builds in `build`.

Actually I have found this through Groovy scripts before, but I cannot find them now. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This groovy script ,when added  in an Extensible Choice parameter, can list out the successful builds from a given job.

```
def builds = []

def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(JOB-NAME)
job.builds.each {
def build = it
if (it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS")) {
    it.badgeActions.each {
             builds.add(build.displayName[1..-1])
     }
   }
}

builds.unique();
```

Comment: It works, btw, ```displayName[1..-1]``` should be ```displayName``` or ```displayName[0..-1]```